# angular js : controller and service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have one service method   items.getItems();

```
getItems: function(callback){      
            $http({
                 url: url,
                 method: "POST"
             }).success(function(data, status){             

                             callback(data);                        
                        }                                                                   
             }).error(function(err){
                 console.error('Error: %s error: %O', 'getLanguages[*] failed.', err);
             });
        }
```

I use it in my controller, I would like to call it inside the function:

```
$scope.param= function(){
 items.getItems(function(data){
        $scope.selectedItemsUpdate = data;
    });
return $scope.selectedItemsUpdate}
```

and  in my html page to do like something :

```
<div data-dy-item data-items="param()"                        
                </div>
```

But it doens't work

Comment: This may not be the actual problem, but I think using `function` as the name of a `function`, even if allowed by Javascript, is a Bad Thing (TM). Apart from the documentational gaffe, I don't think it will fly will with IE9 and lower.

Comment: What is "data-dy-item" and "data-items"? Are they angular directives?

Comment: What does not work? Also, please provide more of the directives.

Answer (score 0):

The call is asynchronous. When the service method returns, the callback has not been called yet. So the controller function will always return undefined (or the previous value of selectedItemsUpdate). The AJAX response needs to come back for the callback to be called. So the code should be:

```
$scope.param = function(){
 items.getItems(function(data) {
    $scope.selectedItemsUpdate = data;
  });
}
```

And the HTML should be

```
<div data-dy-item data-items="selectedItemsUpdate"></div>
```

Of course, the params() function must be called at some time. It should probably be called when the controller is instantiated, or when some button is clicked.

Comment: I think this is just guess work: The original problem is not very clear. Hope you are right, though.